# Perl script to join multiple lines into single line after a delimiter

Tags: perl

I am getting the messages from the remote system , the response are multi line and i have to convert it into single line based on the delimiter.

the contents of stream reader are like below

```
Iam in first Line
Iam in second Line
:

Iam in third Line
Iam  in the forth Line
Iam in fifth Line
:

Iam in Sixth Line
Iam In seventh Line
IAm in Eighth Line
:
```

Multiple lines of the response should be converted into single until the delimiter ":"

Please note that im reading it from the remote system, not from a file,its continuous and doesnt have an eof.until the connection with the remote system terminates

Output should be :

```
Iam in first Line Iam in second Line:
Iam in third Line Iam in the forth Line:
Iam in Sixth Line Iam In Seventh Line Iam in Eighth Line:
```

Can someone please help with an approach or command to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried?  Post whatever code you have written.  Please also read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on writing good SO questions.  Hint: Asking someone to do your work for you is not considered appropriate.

Comment: Sorry..I couldnt add my codes in the question...as it was throwing some error...had to remove it eventually..

Answer (score 4):

One way:

```
$ perl -pne 'chomp unless(/^:/);' file
Iam in first LineIam in second Line:
Iam in third LineIam  in the forth LineIam in fifth Line:
Iam in Sixth LineIam In seventh LineIAm in Eighth Line:
```

Comment: Well...I want to embedded this code snippet in my existing perl script...where read it from the remote system not from the file..

$_ = <READPIPE>;

$_ has the above messages, I tried using the chomp unless command ..but it doesnt seem to work. Is there any other alterantive..

Comment: Add the code in single quotes immediately after your $_=<READ...>

Comment: @Prez27 You can run the one liner with the command switch `-MO=Deparse` to see the full code: `perl -MO=Deparse -pe'chomp unless /^:/'` gives something like `while (defined($_ = <PIPE>)) {chomp $_ unless /^:/} continue {die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_}`

Answer (score -1):

```
perl -p -e 's/\n/ /g;s/:[\s]*/:\n/g' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
Iam in first Line
Iam in second Line
:

Iam in third Line
Iam  in the forth Line
Iam in fifth Line
:

Iam in Sixth Line
Iam In seventh Line
IAm in Eighth Line
:
> perl -p -e 's/\n/ /g;s/:[\s]*/:\n/g' temp
Iam in first Line Iam in second Line :
 Iam in third Line Iam  in the forth Line Iam in fifth Line :
 Iam in Sixth Line Iam In seventh Line IAm in Eighth Line :
>
```

Comment: How to embed the above command in my perl script.where read it from the remote system not from the file.. $_ = <READPIPE>; $_ has the above messages. Also can you explain where you are checking for the delimiter ":" in the above code snippet